# XForms Orbeon: how to limit exforms:sort on "load form" only (block sort when user is typing)

Tags: sorting, orbeon

I have an instance which is loaded with a few lines, (e.g. 3 lines, each having last name, first name):

```
<users>
  <user>
    <last-name>Smith</last-name>
    <last-name>John</last-name>
  </user>
  <user>
    <last-name>Doe</last-name>
    <last-name>John</last-name>
  </user>
  <user>
    <last-name>Xanadu</last-name>
    <last-name>Juliet</last-name>
  </user>
</user>
```

the connected user can modify in the grid the last name or first name.

My problem is that I used:

```
<xforms:repeat nodeset="exforms:sort(./user, 'last_name', 'text', 'ascending')">
```

for the display, which means that everytime the user modifies (letter by letter) the last name, the sorting may change dynamically, resulting on the connected user typing in the wrong place, or losing his way.

Is there a way to sort the grid on first load of screen and then block sorting while on "write mode"?

Am I doing it the wrong way ?

My goal is to display the lines sorted by last name, allow the user to modify what he wants (with no dynamic sorting), then save the data (which are sorted again when next displayed).

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with an action. Place the following within your `<xf:model>` (assuming here that your `<users>` are in an instance called `my-instance`):

```
<xf:action event="xforms-model-construct-done">

    <xf:var
        name="original-users"
        value="instance('my-instance')/user"/>

    <xf:delete
        ref="$original-users"/>

    <xf:insert
        context="instance('my-instance')"
        origin="exf:sort($original-users, 'last_name', 'text', 'ascending')"/>

</xf:action>
```